# can i access a unix domain socket on a remote machine?

Tags: python, sockets, unix, multiprocessing

I have a Python process on a single box which creates a flock of mini servers, small Python processes which provide some specialized computation. Each of those creates and listens on a Unix domain socket using `multiprocessing.connection.Listener ("file_path")`, each with a different path, of course.

Is it possible to access a socket on a remote machine, with something like a path of `unix://remote/file_path`, or `file://remote/file_path`?

Using port numbers is not practical, since the set of mini servers is dynamic.

Comment: No, it's not possible to access Unix domain sockets remotely.

Comment: @Barmar I disagree. You can pass the data from the socket to the network with socat, but for that you need socat on the target system.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 You can access practically anything if you can run a program on the remote system. I interpreted the question as being about accessing the socket directly, not through a proxy application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unix domain sockets are meant for inter-process communication within the same host machine. Data sent through these sockets are handled entirely inside the kernel. For communication between processes in different machines, you should use [network sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket).